# dygraphs - disable legend for two series

Tags: dygraphs

I created Website with a chart, to generate chart I used dygraphs library. Chart displays three series of data (measurement value and tolerances)

[image]

How can I disable legend for tolerances? Is it possible in dygraphs disable legend for one or more series?

Answer (score 3):

Yes. If you're using dygraphs 2.0 or later, you can do this with a [`legendFormatter`](https://github.com/danvk/dygraphs/pull/683). You can customize the formatting of the legend to your heart's content using a `legendFormatter`. But if you just want to hide two series, the easiest way is to remove your Min and Max series from the `series` array and hand it back to the default formatter:

```
g = new Dygraph(
    document.getElementById("graph"),
    "X,Y,min,max\n" +
    "1,6,3,12\n" +
    "2,3,3,12\n" +
    "3,4,3,12\n" +
    "4,6,3,12\n" +
    "5,8,3,12\n" +
    "6,10,3,12\n" +
    "7,12,3,12\n" +
    "8,10,3,12\n",
    {
      legend: 'always',
      series: {
        min: { color: 'red' },
        max: { color: 'red' },
      },
      legendFormatter: function(data) {
        data.series = [data.series[0]];  // pick whichever series you want to keep
        return Dygraph.Plugins.Legend.defaultFormatter.call(this, data);
      }
    });
```

See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eM2Mg/9266/).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the this function to format the legend-

```
LegendFormatter(data) {
if (data.x == null) {
  // This happens when there's no selection and {legend: 'always'} is set.
  return data.series.map(function(series) { 
if(series.labelHTML != 'counter_label')
return series.dashHTML + ' ' + series.labelHTML }).join('&emsp;');
}
var html = data.xHTML;
return html;
}
```

The above code will return all the legend except the series having label as 'counter_label'. Make necessary amendments in the code for applying two conditions for your requirement.

And while defining the graph use the below format for specifying the graph:

```
this.graph = new Dygraph(document.getElementById("graph_div"), 
    this.data,
    {
      legend: 'always',
      drawPoints: true,
      animatedZooms: true,
      showRoller: true,
      rollPeriod: 14,
      legendFormatter: this.LegendFormatter,
    });
```

Here the legendformatter function will be use to format the legend according to the requirement.